# Unique constraint on any combination of two columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to implement a unique constraint for a combination of two columns. I am running oracle 11g.

Specifically I have two columns A and B.

I have a row like below

```
A     B
1     2
```

Then I want the following combinations to fail when inserted

```
A     B
1     2
2     1
```

Is this possible to achieve with a unique index in Oracle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible(for example using generated columns):

```
CREATE TABLE tab(A INT NOT NULL, B INT NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE tab ADD c1 AS (LEAST(A,B));
ALTER TABLE tab ADD c2 AS (GREATEST(A,B));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_tab ON tab(c1,c2);
```

You could hide these columns if needed(Oracle 12c):

```
ALTER TABLE tab MODIFY c1 INVISIBLE;
ALTER TABLE tab MODIFY c2 INVISIBLE;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee458eed95c203acef89999e5d68bf81)**

## EDIT:

Even simpler approach:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_tab ON tab(least(A,B), greatest(A,B));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f8f4a19acb00c99b7f17e7aef7aa8b31)**

Comment: @wolφi  Specific example when it fails, please. Columns are computed.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that `GENERATED ALWAYS' or 'VIRTUAL' is mandatory, but it isn't.

Comment: This does not work if one of the column values is `NULL`.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks, I've assumed that both columns are not nullable. But I see that you extend my anwser with COALESCE so I will leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, that answers my question. MT0 also brings up a good point but my columns are already marked not nullable so this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UNIQUE INDEX` with `LEAST`, `GREATEST` and `COALESCE` functions:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  a INT,
  b INT
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name__a__b__u ON TABLE_NAME(
  COALESCE( LEAST( a, b ), a, b ),
  GREATEST( a, b )
);
```

You need to include `COALESCE` in case one of the values is `NULL`.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0513885e5eb5748b397c6b513959ca84)

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( a, b ) VALUES ( 1, 2 );
1 rows affected
INSERT INTO table_name ( a, b ) VALUES ( 3, NULL );
1 rows affected
INSERT INTO table_name ( a, b ) VALUES ( 2, 1 );
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME__A__B__U) violated
INSERT INTO table_name ( a, b ) VALUES ( NULL, 3 );
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME__A__B__U) violated
```